# Allowing current_user to email @user from users#show/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I've set up Rails 4 ActionMailer to send me (as site admin) an email whenever a new user signs up (registrations#create - I'm using Devise).

Now I would like for current_user to be able to email the user whose profile they are currently viewing. So in `users#show` I'd like to have a form that simply generates an email `:to @user.email`, `:from current_user.email` (optionally override-able via text input), and possibly a body to the message.

A record of the message is not important. For this implementation I'm letting the users' inboxes handle all of the history. In fact I'd rather not store that data if it's possible to just pass it through the model/controller. If the addition of body text necessitates the use of a `MessagesController` then I would rather leave that out.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <%= form_for(Message.new) do |f| %>
          <div class="form-inputs">
            <%= f.text)area :message %>
          </div>
          <%= f.hidden_field :sender_email, value: current_user.email %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :receiver_email, value: @user.email %>

          <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit">Email</button>
          </div>
      <% end %>
```

Your message model will look like this

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Model


  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

Message controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController


  def create
    @message = Message.new(params.require(:message).permit(:sender_email, :receiver_email, :message))
    if @message.valid?
      MessageMailer.send_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to profile_url, notice: "Message sent"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end

class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_message(message)
    @body = message.message
    @from = message.sender_email
    @to = message.receiver_email
    mail to: @to, :subject => "new mail", :from => @from
  end
end
```

The above code is not tested hope it works for your need

Comment: Doesn't seem like this would support the form submission from the Users controller. Currently getting `undefined method `messages_path'`  error

Comment: add `resources :messages` to your route file